# Need to find an unique number in an array

Tags: c++, algorithm, implementation

This is the problem (in brief):

> We're given an array with N natural numbers and a val K. We need to
> find the number in the array which appears a single time knowing that
> any other number in my array appears exacly K times.
>
> We need to find that number.

**Restrictions and specifications**

> 200.000 <= N <= 300.000 
>  2 <= K <= 15 
>  Any number in my array is a natural number between **0 ... 2^64-1**

Memory & execution time restriction:

> Memory: 0.5 Mb 
>  Time: 0.6 seconds

Example:

```
Type:

N K
<array vals>

10 3
1 3 5 7 5 1 3 1 5 3
```

---

That's it. *My main problem is how to deal with such large numbers in my array* ( `0 ... 2^64-1` ).

My idea sounds like that (supposing that the numbers are from `0 to 9`):
-> I count the occurences of my each digit (number) from my array and I mark it (the number) as computed.

-> I iterate from 0 to 9 and if the digit is computed (=I have that number in my array) and the occurences of that digit is different from K, I solved the problem.

But again, my numbers are from `0 to 2^64-1`, I can't declare an array with 2^64 dimension!

Can you guys give me an idea?

Comment: *"how to deal with such large numbers in my array ( 0 ... 2^64-1 )."* With `uint64_t` and `#include <stdint.h>`

Comment: You're going to want a `bitmap` somehow. Can't think of an exact solution or algorithm for you offhand, but will report back if I do.

Comment: Please choose at most one of C and C++.

Comment: This looks like homework or a challenge. Finding a solution is part of your test. SO you should start with picking **one** language and researching what the language provides.

Comment: Yup @WeatherVane but I need to declare some arrays with such dimension!

Comment: You don't need an array size (2^64)-1. the question says `200.000 <= N <= 300.000` (floating point not required!) `uint64_t array[301];`

Comment: @Olaf sorry to tell you but it's not true.

Comment: @WeatherVane sorry to ask you, but what's floating point and why you declared only with 301 elements?

Comment: I declared 301 elements because N can be 300. If you want to index an array by `[300]` it needs at least 301 elements.

Comment: I think that point is a thousands separator, not a decimal separator.  There can be up to three hundred thousand integers, each one of which is 8 bytes.  Reading them all into memory will take nearly 2.5 M memory.

Comment: @MartinBonner good guess, but 300000 elements is still easily do-able with most modern machines. 2.5M? I have 2GB free right now.

Comment: Yes, but this is a (silly) programming challenge - and one of the limitations is 0.5Mb

Comment: @MartinBonner oops missed that.

Comment: @WeatherVane I don't know what's that floatin point and how it works. Do you know any tutorial or something?

Comment: Sorry I can't recommend any C tutorials. Perhaps Mr internet search can, quicker than I can do it and post it on.

Comment: You can have a look at my answer. It accomplishes what you were looking for :)

Comment: I expect the 200.000 and 300.000 is a non US use of '.' so those mean 200K and 300K (I don't recall which countries write numbers that way).  But then the input data is over 0.5MB so how to interpret that restriction?

Comment: @JSF: Germany for instance. That's what localisation is for ... :-)

Comment: @WeatherVane: 500KiB.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do this in fast linear time with less than 100 bytes of extra space.

If K is even, then just XOR all the elements together and you're done.

Think about how that works -- one way to think about that xor operation is that it considers each bit to be a separate number.  It adds them together and produces the result mod 2.  Anything multiplied by an even number is 0 mod 2, so only the bits that were set in the number that appears once remain set.

If K is not even, then you can do the very same job, but mod K (or factor of K -- either 3 or 5) instead of mod 2.

Given:

```
int K,N;  //input values
uint64_t data[N]; //array of numbers
```

The code looks like this:

```
//initialize a counter for each bit in the result
int bitvals[64];
for (int bit=0; bit<64; ++bit)
{
    bitvals[bit]=0;
}

//count the number of times each bit occurs in the array
for(int i=0; i<N; ++i)
{
    uint64_t val=data[i];
    for(int bit=0; bit<64; ++bit)
    {
        if (val & (((uint64_t)1)<<bit))
            bitvals[bit]+=1;
    }
}

//only the bits in the number that occurs once are non-zero mod K
//make that number
uint64_t ret=0;
for(int bit=0; bit<64; ++bit)
{
    if (bitvals[bit]%K)
        ret |= ((uint64_t)1)<<bit;
}
return ret;
```

EXTRA CREDIT:
If you like, this solution can be optimized with bit-parallel additions (JSF's answer points in this direction), but that's probably not necessary for whatever you need it for.  You can use 5 64-bit integers to represent the lower 5 bits of each counter.  Up to 31 input values can be accumulated with these counters before expanding them into the bitvals array.  Accumulating each word would look like this:

```
   for (int i=0;i<5; i++)
   {
      uint64_t carry = parcounters[i]&val;
      parcounters[i]^=val;
      val=carry;
   }
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Can you post the code? I'll think about it and try to implement it and compare it.

Comment: Nice approach, but if K is even, it directly generates the result. Not sure what you mean with `mod 2`. Not sure if that works for odd `K` (btw: please add formating to your text). Can you elaborate?

Comment: @Tib: If he provided the code, there would be nothing left for you to implement.

Comment: This is a real good approach

Comment: I don't think you should actually provide code; there should be something left for OP to do on her own.

Comment: @Olaf I need to understand how to solve this problem, why would I read the code without trying to solve it by myself first?

Comment: @Tib: Simply as one approaches every programming problem: first understand the task. develop a solution. Then implement that. The first two are given already (although I'm still not sure about the odd `K` part).

Comment: I don't understand it either, @MattTimmermans, can you detail it please? I'll accept your answer then

Comment: @MattTimmermans it's not working! Check this code please (it's copied from your post + input): [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/PhKzcf41), run it in shell online compiler or whatever and fix it please, I would appreciate a lot.

Comment: @MattTimmermans in that pastie I forgot a " fin " there (input from text), change it with cin (that's not why the code isn't working, try it please).

Comment: works for me: http://ideone.com/eNhECi

Comment: @MattTimmermans ok, thanks. 2 questions: (1) why  "(uint64_t)1" and not simply "1" ? (2) ret |= ((uint64_t)1)<<bit;   why not "^" to make that bit 1?

Comment: uint64_t, because 1 is an int, and you can't shift an int left by 63 bits. For setting the bit, ^= would have worked as well as |=, but |= is better because it says what I mean

Answer (score 2):

I assume the input is read but too big to store.

So as you read it, count how many times bit N is set for each of 64 bits.  Then take the remainder of each of those counts mod K, which for each bit position is zero or one giving the value of that bit position.

If you don't mind writing a lot of tedious code, you could write six different boolean modular counting routines and select one of them based on the lowest prime factor of K: 2, 3, 5, 7, 11 or 13.

That avoids all the loops over the 64 bits, and should be more than 64 times faster for 2 and likely still more than 8 times faster for the worst case 13.

for example boolean counting mod 3 could be done with:
before the loop `a=b=0` then for each input `x`

```
z = a | b;
a ^= x & ~b;
b ^= x & z;
```

then at the end the result is in `a`

for 5 you could start with `a=b=c=0` and use:

```
b ^= x & a;
a ^= x & ~c;
c ^= x & ~(a|b);
```

7:

```
a ^= x & ~(c & b);
z = x & ~a;
c ^= b & z;
b ^= z;
```

Have fun with 11 and 13.  In all cases the final answer is in `a` with no extra completion work.  Lacking a bug or bad input, at the end `b`, `c` and (if you need it) `d` will all be zero, so that is an easy sanity check.

Comment: Ok, I think this is a similar approach like @matttimmermans, but I think this is better elaborated.

Comment: How do I do this: "count how many times bit N is set for each of 64 bits. Then take the remainder of each of those counts mod K"

Comment: @Olaf I really appreciate all of your comments, thank you for being here!

Comment: @Tib: Ok, I give you one final hint: you need something like `if array[n], bit_I> is set then cntr[i]++`. (this is some kind of meta-language, apparently not C++).

Comment: @Olaf meta-language? Never heard of it :) Anyway, thank you again!

Comment: @Tib: Please do not ask for every phrase. Just google or duckduck yourself. It is just no specific programming language, but a kinda mixture just to make clear what I mean.

Comment: Hmm, I'm really tempted to try implement this (in C, not C++) most efficiently. I think a good idea would be to use the XOR-approach for even `K` and a slower counting as you provide for odd `K`. But there likely is some better way.

Comment: See the bit-parallel addition at the end of my answer above.  It's actually possible (and really fun) to do the whole `v=(v+x)%K` entirely in bit-parallel operations for arbitrary K.  hint: it's implemented like `v+=x;v-=K*(v>=K?1:0);`

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps I am misunderstanding the problem, but here is a way to solve it.

1. Sort the array with an in-place sorting algorithm. since it is in-place, you will not need much more space than the initial array. This is much more space efficient than a map.
2. Iterate through the array, if you find a number without a duplicate, that's your number.

You can even optimize step 2 by iterating over every Kth element and looking to see if the previous number is different. (you still must deal with special cases when target number is biggest or smallest number of the set)

Comment: Don't understand the downvote.  It's more complex than a simple std::map, but it's the other obvious solution.

Comment: @MartinBonner: In fact it is the more efficient version. It is just not clear if the array may be modified.

Comment: In-place sorting algorithm? @SimCard can you detail please?

Comment: In-place means that you do not allocate more than constant memory for your sort. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/In-place_algorithm. A common sort that can be implemented in-place is Quicksort. So essentially, you sort using the space of the original array.

Answer (score -1):

First sort the array and then iterate over it to get the answer. Here is the logic, the unique element can be at any position marked as 0, K, 2K, 3K, .., N-1

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

unsigned long long uniqueNumber(vector<unsigned long long> &arr, int K) {
    sort(arr.begin(), arr.end());
    int i = 0;
    for(i = K-1;i < arr.size();i += K) {
        if(arr[i] != arr[i-K+1])
            return arr[i-K+1];
    }
    return arr[i-K+1];
}

int main()
{
    vector<unsigned long long> A{1, 3, 5, 7, 5, 1, 3, 1, 5, 3};
    cout<<uniqueNumber(A, 3)<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Inefficient and not clear if the array may be modified.

Comment: it's not an efficient way I agree. But I think this approach is correct. Correct me If I am wrong somewhere.

Comment: array's copy will be modified not the actual array

Comment: If you copy the array, you violate size constraint. And the sort might violate time contraint.